# Passing the image selected in cameraroll using class file to component in main mxml

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.6

i  am new to flex and i am trying to develop android app in flash builder 4.6, i have a separate class file which gives access to the camera roll in android, on selecting the image i want to pass that  image to the image component in main MXML file. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication` to access the main mxml file.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexGlobals.html#topLevelApplication

I would have a look at using dependency injection to accomplish what you're trying to do though.
https://swizframework.jira.com/wiki/display/SWIZ/Dependency+Injection

Here's an example app I created for iOS that uses Swiz's dependency injection.
https://github.com/cmodien/MobileSFA/blob/master/code/src/MobileSFA.mxml